# Flatten a collection based on an internal property

Tags: c#, linq

Given the follow class structure:

```
int Id;
string[] Codes;
```

And the following data:

```
Foo { Id = 1, Codes = new[] { "01", "02" } }
Foo { Id = 2, Codes = new[] { "02", "03" } }
Foo { Id = 3, Codes = new[] { "04", "05" } }
```

I would like to end up with the following structure.

```
Code = "01", Id = 1
Code = "02", Id = 1
Code = "02", Id = 2
Code = "03", Id = 2
Code = "04", Id = 3
Code = "05", Id = 3
```

---

I've got the following query, but it's giving me a collection as the Id rather than the flat structure I am after.

```
collection.GroupBy(f => f.Codes.SelectMany(c => c), f => f.Id,
      (code, id) => new { Code = code, Id = id })
   .ToArray()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) can return multiple elements for each item as a single list

```
items
    .SelectMany(foo => foo.Codes.Select(code => new { Id = foo.Id, Code = code }));
```

Comment: I prefer using better naming so the anonymous object picks them up from the values: `items.SelectMany(item => item.Codes.Select(Code => new { item.Id, Code }))`

Comment: @NetMage Looks far better, however I'm in the habit of using single letters then just explicitly naming the anonymous object.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Diego Torres is correct; I would only add to it that this query is particularly concise and readable in the comprehension form:

```
var q = from foo in foos
        from code in foo.Codes
        select new { Code = code, foo.Id };
```